# How to setup for really deep convolution model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolution

I'm rather new to deep learning and convolution network and got some basic models to run. However, when I tried to build a deep CNN model (i.e., more than 14, 15 layers) the error rate does not seem to decrease even after several epochs. So I wonder what could be the problem and how to overcome it?

Comment: Visualize the weights and see what they learned. If convolution + pooling layer is assumed as one layer, 14-15 layers seem to me too much. Posterior convolution layers may try to learn super-abstract features which are probably doesn't exist in the input images [open to discussion].

Comment: 15 layers is *really* *really* deep. Some of the most powerful networks around (like the one that breaks Captcha) are <10 layers.

Answer (score 0):

First, try an optimization method like Adagrad or Adadelta that are more robust to learning rates. Also, make sure your gradient updated are correct (e.g. scipy has a check_grad method).

Given that you have these two correct, I would then try to do greedy layer-wise pre-training in the first layers for some epochs. The reason is that your network is very deep and you will need proper initialisation to start training.

If you are using Torch7 you can have a look at this and use the ConvNet example as pre-training https://github.com/torch/demos/blob/master/train-autoencoder/train-autoencoder.lua.

Comment: Why only the first layer?

Comment: @Oxinabox not only one but, in general the first layers. You are dealing with a very high-dimensional optimisation problem. The intuition behind that is that you start discovering features in a greedy unsupervised way and then you fine-tune everything with supervised training. This helps you avoid many local minima, starting from your optimization from a better than random point.

Comment: I mean why not on all the layers? (except the final classification layer)

Comment: It's your choice, you want a reasonable initialisation, I would say just the first layers for speeding up the process, but both would work.